# What is the difference between "T?" and "T??"

Tags: swift

I understand the following code...

```
var dic1: Dictionary<String, String> = ["key" : "value"]
var str1: String? = dic1["key"]// key is not found => nil => String?
```

But I could not...

```
var dic2: Dictionary<String, String?> = ["key" : nil]
var str3: String?? = dic2["key"]// key is not found or set nil value => nil => why String??
```

What is the necessity of String?? and the difference of String? and String??.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two (or more) optionals in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift).

Comment: Martin, In Dictionary, I understand the existence value of “doubly-nested optional type”. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `String?` and `String??` is the following:

```
let s1 = Optional<String>()           // String?
let s2 = Optional<Optional<String>>() // String??
```

Referencing your example:

The `subscript` of a `Dictionary` returns an optional type.
Therefore, because your value type in `dic2` is a `String?`, you first have to unwrap the optional to determine whether the value exists for that key, then you have to unwrap your `String?`.

Here's an example to demonstrate:

```
if let optionalStringValue = dic2["key"] {
   // A value exists for 'key'.
   if let unwrappedStringValue = optionalString {
       // In Swift 1.2 you could combine these two if let statements.
   }
}
```