# Can Swift optional be nested?

Tags: swift, option-type

I cannot find the answer to this question, for example can I have optional of an optional of a String? I tried to write a small test to check it out:

```
let a : String? = nil;
let b : String?? = a;
if b!=nil { // error
  println("has value");
}
else {
  println("fail");
}
```

but since I am not a Swift programmer I don't know what to do with error saying "cannot assign to the result of this expression".

Comment: Someone's going to ask: why would you want it to be? I'm going to note that, while researching an answer.

Comment: @Tommy, I **WAITED** for that comment :-) I am comparing the nullable/optional approaches in the programming languages, I can trade you a small fact -- in Kotlin, it is not nested :-)

Comment: Related: [Two (or more) optionals in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift).

Comment: Your syntax error is completely unrelated to optionals. `let a = 1 ; let b = 2 ; if a!=b { }` without spaces around the `!=` operator would not compile either.

Comment: (Note that `println` is from Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.4 which is outdated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can; your syntax is incorrect though. This line:

```
if b!=nil
```

Is digested by the compiler as:

```
if (b!) = nil
```

... so it thinks you're trying to assign `nil` to the unwrapped optional. Swift doesn't allow you to make assignments within `if` statements (in contrast to Objective-C). Instead be clearer:

```
if b != nil
```

EDIT: and, to finish the thought, proving that the syntactic sugar really is making an optional optional, if you add:

```
if let b = b {
    print("\(b)")
}
```

You should see `nil` as the printed output.

Comment: Picky compiler :-), so optionals can be nested. Thank you very much!