# Swift - How to check if var is nil?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

I need to check if the last element in a dataArray is nil or not, so I am running this code:

```
 if(dataArray.last == nil){
     print("dataArray.last == nil");
 } else {
     print("dataArray.last != nil , last = " + String(dataArray.last));
 }
```

The weird thing is that it is printing this:

```
dataArray.last != nil , last = Optional(nil)
```

It is saying that the last element is nil despite the if condition not being met. How is this possible?

Additionally, if I print `String(dataArray)` this is what is returned:

```
[itemData,itemData , itemData , nil ,  nil , nil].
```

Comment: That means that you have an array of optionals, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift for a similar issue with dictionary values.

Comment: `if let last = dataArray.last where last == nil {
    print("last is nil")
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first` and `last` methods of array return optional value, that contains nil or element of array. Going forward, element of array can be nil by itself. Let me show easy example:

```
let dataArray: [String?] = ["a", nil]
let lastElement = dataArray.last
```

You think that `lastElement` have type `String?`, but it have type `String??` instead. When you check `dataArray.last` for nil, you only confirm that array is not empty. I offer you to use optional binding instead:

```
if let lastElement = dataArray.last, _ = lastElement{         
    print("dataArray.last != nil , last = " + String(dataArray.last));        
}else{
    print("dataArray is empty OR last element of dataArray is nil");
}
```

Comment: You explained why the problem occurs, but your code is equivalent to the one in the question, and produces the same output.

Comment: @MartinR you are right, thanks for pointing. answer corrected

Comment: You're using `if let` to conditionally assign `dataArray.last` to `lastElement`, but  then in the if statement body you use `dataArray.last` rather than `lastElement`, thus completely defeating the purpose if the `if let` statement

Comment: @AMomchilov in context of question you should not care about it. I specially made minimum changes in code: I let unnamed var `_` and unwrapped `dataArray.last`, which will output visual information about doubled Optional type.

Answer (score 4):

As also explained in the other answers, the `last` property of a 
collection of `Element` has the type `Element?`, and returns `nil`
if the collection is empty. In your case, the element type itself is
an optional type `Item?`, so there are three cases possible:

1. The array is empty: `dataArray.last` is `nil` aka `.None`.
2. The array is not empty, and the last element is `nil`:
   `dataArray.last` is `.Some(nil)`.
3. The array is not empty, and the last element is not `nil`:
   `dataArray.last` is `.Some(.Some(element)`.

If you want do distinguish all three cases, you have to unwrap
twice:

```
let dataArray: [String?] = [ "a", "b", "c", nil ] // As an example

if let lastElement = dataArray.last {
    if let lastUnwrapped = lastElement {
        print("Last element is", lastUnwrapped)
    } else {
        print("Last element is nil")
    }
} else {
    print("Array is empty")
}
```

This can be shorted with a switch and the optional pattern:

```
switch dataArray.last {
case let element??:
    print("Last element is", element)
case let element?:
    print("Last element is nil")
case nil:
    print("Array is empty")
}
```

If you are only interested if the last element of the array is not `nil`,
then you can use `if case` with an optional pattern:

```
if case let element?? = dataArray.last {
    print("Last element is", element)
} else {
    print("Last element is nil, or array is empty")
}
```

Here `element??` is a shortcut for `.Some(.Some(element))` which
matches case #3.

---

If you want to re-implement the `last` method for arrays then it
would simply be

```
extension Array {
    func lastMe() -> Element? {
        if isEmpty {
            return nil
        } else {
            return self[count - 1]
        }
    }
}
```

If the element type is an optional `Item?`, then the return type
becomes `Item??`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i just want to let you know that i declare dataArray: [itemData!] . does this different than dataArray: [itemData?]

Comment: martin !, thank you very much that's very helpful , but can you please show me how the last function is implemented . i just want to know how to return optiona(nil) . Thanks

Comment: @david: I have fixed the last method (after vacawama's comment), now all three work with implicitly unwrapped optionals as well.

Comment: @vacawama & Martin Thanks again. but can you please show me how the last function is implemented. what i mean is : i need to create function which accept an array and return last . just to understand how last is woking

Comment: @david: And what should that function return if the array is empty? Or if the last element is nil?

Comment: it should return the same as dataarray.last but without the using of dataarray.last !

Comment: @david: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you update your question with examples of input and expected output?

Comment: Martin! i've edited the question , i just want to understand how to implement array.last function

Comment: @david: See update – not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Martin , Thanks Again. yes that's what i was looking for . i just confused a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

### Why are you getting that result?

Let's look at this code

```
let dataArray: [Int?] = [1, nil]

if let last = dataArray.last {
    print(last)
}
```

It does print

```
nil
```

It does happen because dataArray is defined as an array of optional `Int` (aka `Int?`). So the `last` property does return a value that is an `Optional` containing `nil`.

So the `if` clause is satisfied and the body of the `if` is executed.

### This is the correct syntax

```
let dataArray: [Int?] = [1, nil ,3]

if let lastOptional = dataArray.last, last = lastOptional {
    print("dataArray.last != nil, last = \(last)")
} else {
    print("dataArray.last == nil")
}
```

Output:

```
dataArray.last != nil, last = 3
```

### Explanation

Let's look at the `if`. It is made of 2 clauses and both must be satisfied for the `if` to be resolved as `true`.

**The #1 clause**

```
let lastOptional = dataArray.last
```

does succeed if the last element does exist. It will be an `Int?` so an optional value containing `nil` or an `Int`. In both case this clause is satisfied.

> Basically the first clause is satisfied when the array is **NOT** empty.

**The #2 clause**

```
last = lastOptional
```

does succeed if the optional last (Int?) element is successfully unwrapped.

> This clause is satisfied when the last element does exists and is not an Optional containing `nil`.

### Wrap-up

Inside the body of the `if` you can use `last` and you can be sure that it will be the unwrapped value. Infact the type of last is `Int`.

Comment: Your example is not an array of optionals (as in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if let lastObject = dataArray.last{

            print("dataArray.last != nil", + String(lastObject));
        }else{

            print("dataArray.last == nil );
        }
```

Comment: "Try this" answers without any explanation are not really helpful.

Comment: Probably because the syntax is generally `if let _ = ... ` and not with `if var`, `guard` statement can probably be used in this case too.

Comment: @MartinR I wrote this answer because if it worked i would explain that to him why it was happening and its the correct answer.Please don't down vote without any real reason.

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq: I tried to explain thy this is not a good answer, but I haven't voted on it (yet). – Don't assume any voting without any real reason!

Answer (score 0):

Array have optional function

> last

Optional(nil) is not equal to nil

if you print out dataArray.last then Optional(nil) will be printed

try this

```
if let _ = dataArray.last {
     print("dataArray.last != nil , last = " + String(dataArray.last));
}else{
     print("dataArray.last == nil");
}
```

Comment: My answer was first, sorry =)

Comment: you are right ! second way was edited correctly thank you :)

Comment: @SwiftyCruz: Your first code snipped will crash if the array is empty.

Comment: @appzYourLife that's write first code is minimum changed from writer's code, second is accurate :)

Comment: @SwiftyCruz: but you did write `try this` and it does __NOT__ compile. Please fix your answer.

Comment: @SwiftyCruz The 1st snipped still does not compile.

Comment: @appzYourLife sorry .. i deleted it