# How can I use try with the coalescing operator?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to assign a value to `x` from a function `f` that takes one parameter (a string) and throws.

The current scope throws so I believe a `do`...`catch` isn't required.

I'm trying to use `try` with the coalescing operator `??` but I'm getting this error: `'try' cannot appear to the right of a non-assignment operator`.

```
guard let x = try f("a") ??
              try f("b") ??
              try f("c") else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid value for x")
    return
}
```

If I change `try` to `try?`:

```
guard let x = try? f("a") ??
              try? f("b") ??
              try? f("c") else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid value for x")
    return
}
```

I get the warning `Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'String??', so the right side is never used` and the error: `'try?' cannot appear to the right of a non-assignment operator`.

If I put each try? in brackets:

```
guard let x = (try? f("a")) ??
              (try? f("b")) ??
              (try? f("c")) else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid value for x")
    return
}
```

It compiles but x is an optional and I would like it to be unwrapped.

if I remove the questions marks:

```
guard let x = (try f("a")) ??
              (try f("b")) ??
              (try f("c")) else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid value for x")
    return
}
```

I get the error `Operator can throw but expression is not marked with 'try'`.

I'm using Swift 4.2 (latest in Xcode at time of writing).

What is the correct way to do this to get an unwrapped value in `x`?

**Update:*** `f()`'s return type is String?. I think the fact that it's an optional string is important.

Comment: I think that you should start by removing duplicates and do something like `let x = ['a', 'b', 'c'].lazy.compactMap { try? f($0) }.first`.

Comment: A single `try` can cover the entire expression, e.g `guard let x = try f("a") ?? f("b") ?? f("c") else {...}`

Comment: @Hamish Your suggestion fixes my error _and_ makes my code more readable. Thank you! Please feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Hamish Won't that stop on the first error though? I think it works differently than the original code.

Comment: @Sulthan The `try` keyword doesn't actually have any effect on a program's behaviour, the compiler just requires it in order to make error throwing explicit. No matter where you place the keyword, the function will exit upon the first thrown error.

Comment: @JoshParadroid Sure thing!

Comment: Related: [Function throws AND returns optional.. possible to conditionally unwrap in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691178/function-throws-and-returns-optional-possible-to-conditionally-unwrap-in-one-l)

Comment: @hamish to make myself clear, it wont have the same functionality as the version with `try?` which will continue executing after errors.

Comment: @Sulthan Ah right, yup that's correct. Sorry, when you said "original code" I assumed you were referring to the first code block in OP's question. As I understand it, the `try` behaviour is the one OP wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A single `try` can cover the entire expression, so you can just say:

```
  guard let x = try f("a") ?? f("b") ?? f("c") else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid value for x")
    return
  }
```

Same goes for `try?`:

```
  guard let x = try? f("a") ?? f("b") ?? f("c") else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid value for x")
    return
  }
```

Although note that in Swift 4.2 `x` will be `String?` due to the fact that you're applying `try?` to an already optional value, giving you a doubly-wrapped optional which `guard let` will only unwrap one layer of.

To remedy this, you could coalesce to `nil`:

```
  guard let x = (try? f("a") ?? f("b") ?? f("c")) ?? nil else {
    print("Couldn't get a valid value for x")
    return
  }
```

But in Swift 5 this is unnecessary due to [SE-0230](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0230-flatten-optional-try.md), where `try? f("a") ?? f("b") ?? f("c")` will be flattened into a single optional value automatically by the compiler.

Comment: An alternative for Swift < 5 would be a (double) optional pattern: `guard case let x?? = try? f("a") ?? f("b") ?? f("c")`