# Using nil-coalescing operator with try? for function that throws and returns optional

Tags: swift, error-handling, option-type

I want to use nil-coalescing operator to set a default value in both the following cases:

1. function throws an error
2. function returns nil

Please take a look at the code snippet below. I have the following questions:

1. Why is item1 nil?
2. What is the difference between the initialization of item1 vs item2

```
enum VendingMachineError: Error {
    case invalidCode
}

class VendingMachine {
    func itemCode(code: Int) throws -> String? {
        guard code > 0 else {
            throw VendingMachineError.invalidCode
        }
        if code == 1 {
            return nil
        } else {
            return "Item #" + String(code)
        }
    }
}

let machine = VendingMachine()

// Question: Why is this nil?
let item1 = try? machine.itemCode(code: 0) ?? "Unknown"
print(item1)
// nil

// What is the difference between the initialization of item1 vs item2
let item2 = (try? machine.itemCode(code: 0)) ?? "Unknown"
print(item2)
// Unknown
```

Comment: Btw, the behavior of `try?` with an optional expression changed in Swift 5, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/39691178/1187415. Previously it evaluated to a “double optional” value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially, this has to do with the grammar of the `try` operator. When used with a binary expression without brackets, [`try` applies to the whole binary expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID385), so this:

```
try? machine.itemCode(code: 0) ?? "Unknown"
```

is the same as:

```
try? (machine.itemCode(code: 0) ?? "Unknown")
```

Since `itemCode` throws an error, the latter part of the expression `?? "Unknown` is ignored, and the `try?` expression evaluates to nil.

On the other hand, the second expression is like this:

```
(try? machine.itemCode(code: 0)) ?? "Unknown"
```

The `try?` expression is evaluated first (to nil), then the `??` is applied, evaluating the whole expression to "Unknown".

Comment: Nitpicking: I *think* that `try` is not an operator but a keyword. The “precedence” is induced  by the grammar, not by operator precedence. (Compare "expression", "primary-expression" and "parenthesized-expression" in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html.)

Comment: @MartinR [The Language Reference calls it an operator though](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_try-operator)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But, unless I am mistaken, there is no precedence (group) defined for that “operator.”

Comment: @MartinR Ok, I see what you mean.