# Does Swift allow a quick try-else construct?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to do something like

```
doc = try? Doc(url) else Doc()
```

Is there a way to do something clean like that without much ado? I tried

```
doc = try? Doc(url) : Doc()
```

But that didn't work

Comment: you can use nil coalescing operator `doc = (try? Doc(url)) ?? Doc()`

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57568204/1187415.

Comment: If you do this often, create yourself an extension: `extension Doc { convenience init(maybeUrl url: URL) { do { try self.init(url) } catch { self.init() }}}` and then do `doc = Doc(maybeUrl: url)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using nil-coalescing operator with try? for function that throws and returns optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57568204/using-nil-coalescing-operator-with-try-for-function-that-throws-and-returns-opt)