# Why does Swift allow double optionals?

Tags: swift, monads

The first thing that I thought of when seeing optionals was that it was basically the Maybe monad from ml-style languages. However, a true monad should not double-wrap things (`m(m(a)) == m(a)`). In what situation would you want a double optional rather than a linked list structure?

By "double optional", I mean a type signature of `String??` or something similar. in my mind this should be automatically converted to `String?`.

Comment: Way too theoretical for a question. Care to give us a Swift example of what *you* mean by "double optional". Please include it in your question - I actually think you have the start of a GREAT question!

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225232/two-or-more-optionals-in-swift

Comment: I disagree with the initial statement that a monad should be flattened on any occasion (or how should we read it?). It's OK to have `Optional<Optional<T>>`, and you _can_ flatten things when you need (`.flatMap()` does it; kind of "bind")

Comment: @werediver it wasn't really an opinion, it's part of the monad laws. it's fine to say that optionals should not be monadic, but what I am asking for is a situation in which something like `String??` adds any value over just `String?`.

Comment: Double optionals are needed because you can have optionals of any type, including optionals of other optionals. And it's often necessary to distinguish on which level the `nil` is.

Comment: @SamSchick I can't read monad laws in such a way.

Comment: @dfd what would the right place to ask more theoretical questions be? I get that this is in no way practical, but it's still something I'm curious about.

Comment: @werediver look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#fmap_and_join)

Comment: I'm unsure of the definition of a "straw man argument", but I believe you just did that. The *real* bottom line is this is *not* a place to ask questions that provoke opinionated answers. (And yes, I still think with some specifics on code and issues, this can be a great question.) From this link (https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) about  poor questions for this site: *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."*

Comment: @SamSchick Still can't read the monad laws the way you do. Is Haskell a good example? `Just Just 1` gives you exactly `Just Just 1`, not `Just 1`.

Comment: @dfd, I hear what you're saying, I was hoping you could point me to some place that might be more ok with a theoretical question. an open ended discussion is exactly what I want; what is the right place for that?

Comment: @SamSchick If you're looking for theory, you might consider http://cs.stackexchange.com (and specifically, potentially the `type-theory` and `category-theory` tags).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to try and answer this from a Swift perspective, so forgive me if my FP terminology is incorrect.

**Why would I ever use double optionals?**

There is one well known case for double optional. A collection that uses optional to indicate no value at this key, which is also storing values which might be optional. Here it might be important to know whether the collection or the element returned the nil.

```
let possibleNumbers: [String: Int?] = [:]
guard let possibleNumber = possibleNumbers["one"] else {
     print("No number stored")
}
guard let number = possibleNumber else {
    print("Number at key was nil")
}
```

**Can we automatically convert `T???????` to `T?`?**

No, but it can be achieved with `flatMap`. Although you need to add a new map for each level of optional.

```
possibleNumbers["one"].flatMap { $0 }
```

Also I do not believe the Swift `Optional` is ever explicitly called a monad. It is implemented as a generic enum internally and it follows the semantics of that type more closely. At least I cannot find any reference in the language guide https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: I think you're right that it isn't explicitly called a monad anywhere, it was just that when I saw it described that was immediately what came to mind. I guess the deep unnesting problem is what bothers me about this, but you did give a use case for it.

Comment: Unofficially, it's occasionally claimed around the web that Optional is monadic. Here's a prominent source: http://chris.eidhof.nl/post/monads-in-swift/ It's also worth noting that directly returning `Optional<Optional<Value>>` is not the only solution for a lookup. An out-of-band signal could be used. For example, Python dictionaries can contain `None`, but `None` cannot wrap another value. Therefore, a failed lookup causes an "exception" (which are used very differently in Python than in Swift). It's questionable which is less awkward... @Sam

Comment: Another place where this crops up is iterators. Swift and Python actually have very similar protocols for this. Again, the difference is that Swift uses a optional (which may wrap another optional) to signal the end, whereas Python uses a `StopIteration` exception.