# What's the Purpose of "an Optional of an Optional" in Swift Optional Types?

Tags: swift, option-type

I found an interesting function in the [Swift Tests source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Interpreter/optional.swift#L21):

```
func test(_ v: A????, _ cast: (A????) -> B?)
```

Since `Type?` is just syntax sugar for `Optional<Type>`, this means that the type of the argument `v` can be rewritten as `Optional<Optional<Optional<Optional<A>>>>`.

I know that this function is used to test optional types, so it is definitely going overboard with the arguments `v` and `cast`, but what would be the actual use of having "an optional of an an optional, etc." type in Swift (if any)?

Comment: [OT] I think that more than one nested `Optional` reveals carelessness of the developer 

Comment: Related: [Two (or more) optionals in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27225232/1187415)

Comment: @vadian Eh, if it's intentionally sought after, perhaps. But usually, it's just an inevitable consequence of something like `.first` on an array of optionals, or `try?` on a method that returns an optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These occur sometimes in Swift when you are accessing data.

One example is if you have a dictionary with an optional type for the value, and then you look up a value in that dictionary:

```
let rockStars: [String: String?] = ["Sting": nil, "Elvis": "Presley", "Bono": nil, "Madonna": nil]

let lastName = rockStars["Elvis"]
print(lastName as Any)
```

> > ```
> > Optional(Optional("Presley"))
> > ```

This happens because a dictionary look up can fail when the *key* is not present, and it returns `nil` in that case.  So the return type of a dictionary lookup has to be the value type wrapped in an optional.  A look up from the `rockStars` dictionary returns a `String??`.

Comment: Another example: iterators signal they've reached the end by returning `nil` from `next()`. If the underlying type is optional, then they may return `.some(nil)` during iteration, but signal the end of iteration by returning `.none`.